# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable - import error?

Tags: python

I'm creating a driver file for two class programs I have created.
I have a class called Inventory:

```py
class Inventory:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = []
    
    def addItem(self,id,name,amt,cost):
        addingItem = Item(pn,id,name,amt,cost)
        self.inventory.append(addingItem)
```

and a class Item:

```py
class Item:
    
    def __init__(self,id=0,name="",amt=0,cost=0.0):
        self.itemNo = id
        self.itemName = name
        self.quantity = amt
        self.price = cost
```

I have created a driver file to test this and play around:

```py
item1 = Item.Item(0,"Hat", 14, 10.00)
item2 = Item.Item(1,"Socks", 40, 8.00)
    
    
list = Inventory.Inventory()
   
list.addItem(0, "Hat", 14, 10.00)
list.addItem(1, "Socks", 40, 8.00)
```

I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

and it points toward

```py
addingItem = Item(pn,id,name,amt,cost)
```

In my Inventory class. Am I doing something incorrect when importing? Is it possible to fix this error by not editing and code in either of my classes thus making changes only in my driver?

Comment: How can `Item` even be defined in `Inventory` if you never import it?

Answer (score 3):

This error statement TypeError: 'module' object is not callable is raised as you are being confused about the Class name and Module name. The problem is in the import line . You are importing a module, not a class. This happend because the module name and class name have the same name.
If you have a class MyClass in a file called MyClass.py , then you should write:

```
from YourClass import YourClass
```

Comment: so I should have: from Inventory import item ?

Comment: From fileNameOfClass Import ClassName
So I would guess.." from item import Item"

Answer (score 3):

- You should import your classes directly:

  ```
  from Item import Item            # Assuming the file name is Item.py
  from Inventory import Inventory  # Assuming the file name is Inventory.py
  ```

  and then you can do:

  ```
  item1 = Item(0,"Hat", 14, 10.00)
  ```
- Then you use `Item` inside the `Inventory` class, but you didn't **import** `Item` there. Be careful and import it the same way with `from x import y`.
- Also you have an error in the line:

  ```
  addingItem = Item(pn,id,name,amt,cost)
  ```

  what is `pn`? Remove it and it should work:

  ```
  addingItem = Item(id,name,amt,cost)
  ```
- Also avoid using reserved names like `list`, `id` ecc... you might end up with problems.